# Anchor href cursor not clickable but right-click options as a href and cursor changes to href symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been stuck on this silly bug for far to long. I have a Wordpress site which uses Bootstrap for it's navigation bar (horrible system, if I hadn't bought the template I would never used it). The problem is the 'Go-To-Home' image/link is not redirecting the browser to the homepage, yet is acting like a functioning href link.

`<a href="http://wpd.minded-develop.nl/" title="Digitaal Kantoor" class="navbar-brand"><img src="http://wpd.minded-develop.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logo_nav.png" width="153" height="36" alt=""></a>`

With this css for navbar-brand

`#topMenu .navbar-brand {
  padding: 7px 0 0 15px;
}`

It's much easier to check it out yourself: http://wpd.minded-develop.nl/voor-wie/

Hope someone knows why this isn't working.

Comment: The link works when I disable JavaScript. This implies that there is some kind of `click` event associated with links, that is probably `preventDefault`ing

Comment: I've been searching through the click events, the problem is that JQuery adds so much I have no idea where to start looking

Comment: Your link works fine if you disable Javascript, so you can assume it is a script hijacking the click. Start disabling your plugins one-by-one.

Comment: Is there be a quicker way of doing this? I have a lot of plugins that would need to be deactivated.

Comment: Turn off 50% and *binary halve* the problem. Repeat for each 50% block of plugins within the half that fails. You will find it very fast :)

Comment: The situation seems to be caused by your theme’s usage of [jQuery One Page Nav plugin](http://davist11.github.io/jQuery-One-Page-Nav/). As links with CSS class name _external_ are not handled by this plugin, you could try adding _external_ class to your logo hyperlink and see if that helps. If not, the JavaScript files to look into are _function.js_ and _jquery.nav.js_ in your _/wp-content/themes/deita/resources/js/_ folder.

Comment: When adding the class external with Chrome inspector it does not seem to help anything, would it make a difference if I added this to the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [kaarel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17529/kaarel) answered in the comments, the [jQuery One Page Nav](https://davist11.github.io/jQuery-One-Page-Nav/) plugin hijacking clickevents or doing something nasty with non-external anchor's. I changed this by adding the `external` class to the href.

Answer (score -2):

```
<a href="your link">
<img src="yourimage.png" /> 
</a>
```

at the end of your image u need to put the

```
/>
```

to close ur img

Comment: While that would be an improvement for validation, browsers do not require it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference if I change it with element inspector of Chrome. I'm searching through a jungle of code of my Wordpress theme where the value is set so I can change it hardcoded

Comment: @Martijn Nosyncerror: While this change would make it the IMG XHTML, browsers *do not* require it. You have a script problem.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Oke thanks, I will abort the search through code jungle and return empty handed :)

Comment: When u click on ur logo it turns the div in to active. why?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean? As far as why, I know about as much as you. If this is important I can start searching why this is, but I don't think it's really relevant?